# Restarting a While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Is it possible to restart a while loop? I currently have a while loop that exists within a foreach loop and I need the while statement to start from the beginning each time.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products");
$products = array('Milk', 'Cheese', 'Eggs');
$i = 0;
$total = count($products); //This is in case I change the product list.

if($sql)
{
    foreach($products as $v)
    {
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            if($r['Name'] == $v)
            {
                echo $r['Name'] . " - £" . $r['Price'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem occurs when the code runs and it produces `Milk` and `Eggs` but in the database `Cheese` comes before `Eggs`, and so it never seems to get found. How can I restart the while loop in order to force the code to check for each value from the start of the sql query?

SOLVED: Used hashing in order to query instead of looping sql.

Comment: why restarting that while loop, first fetch all data to an array and do as normal inner loops

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha I've never fetched the data to an array? I assume running a while loop and then a foreach($row) inside that is what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to store the results from the query in a hash for O(1) lookup, rather than reading from sql over and over.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products");
$sql_products = array();
$products = array('Milk', 'Cheese', 'Eggs');
$i = 0;
$total = count($products); //This is in case I change the product list.

if($sql)
{
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $sql_products[$r['Name']] = $r;
    }
    foreach($products as $v)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($v,$sql_products))
        {
            echo $v . " - £" . $sql_products[$v]['Price'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is somewhat similar to what @MansoorkhanCherupuzha said? seems to be storing it in an array?

Comment: Yes, similar. But using a hash rather than an array, so lookups are much faster.

Comment: @MikeShaw, yes this is is what i mean

Comment: Wonderful, worked a charm thank you so much guys! Is there a page on php.net or anything that you can link me to so I can learn more about hashes?